# How to change the object depending value type javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to change the nested object to new object in javascript.

I have a object `obj` in which if details is arrays, then take first array value as value in javascript.

```
function newObj(obj1) {
  let map = {};
  obj1.forEach(e => {
    let details = e.details;
    Object.values(details).forEach(value => {
      if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0) {
        map[value[0]] = value[0];
      }
      else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        Object.values(value).forEach(val => { map[val] = val; });
      }
    })
  });
  return map;
}

var obj1 = [
  {
    details : {
      "info"  : ["stocks", "finance", ""],
      "sales" : ["analytics"]
    }
  }
];
var obj2 = [
  {
    details : {
      "city" : "SG"
    }
  }
];
var r1 = this.newObj(obj1);
var r2 = this.newObj(obj2);
```

Expected Output

```
//for obj1 (show only first value of array)
{
  info  : "stocks",
  sales : "analytics"
}
//obj2
{
  city : "SG"
}
```

Comment: @Teemu I have updated code, thanks for reply

Comment: Put `r1` & `r2` after `obj1` & `obj2`?
Why `this.`?

Comment: `obj2` is invalid. What is `{"SG"}`? Do you mean `["SG"]`?

Comment: @iAmOren thanks fore reply, updated code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overcomplicated this. Look at the example below. The logic goes like this:

1. Iterate over `details` **keys**
2. If a *value* under the *key* is an array, then create the `key` in the `map` and assign the `value[0]`
3. If a *value* under the *key* is not an array, then simply copy its value into the `map`

And that's enough to achieve what you want.

```js
function newObj(obj){
  let map = {};
  obj.forEach(e => {
    let details = e.details;
    Object.keys(details).forEach(key => {
      var value = details[key];
      if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0){
        map[key] = value[0];
      } else {
        map[key] = value;
      }
    });
  });
  return map;
}

var obj1 = [
  {
    details: {
      "info":["stocks","finance",""],
      "sales":["analytics"]
    }
  }
];

var obj2 = [
  {
    details: {
        "city":"SG"
    }
  }
];

var r1 = newObj(obj1);
var r2 = newObj(obj2);

console.log(r1);
console.log(r2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very concise solution thanks to destructuring assignments:

```js
function newObj(obj) {
    const [{ details }] = obj;
    const entries = Object.entries(details)
        .map(([key, value]) => ([key, Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value]));
    return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}
```

Live example:

```js
'use strict';

function newObj(obj) {
    const [{ details }] = obj;
    const entries = Object.entries(details)
        .map(([key, value]) => ([key, Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value]));
    return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}

const obj1 = [
    {
        details: {
            info: ['stocks', 'finance', ''],
            sales: ['analytics']
        }
    }
];

const obj2 = [
    {
        details: {
            city: 'SG'
        }
    }
];

console.log(newObj(obj1));
console.log(newObj(obj2));
```